# Using Scala lists in Spark SQL queries

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
val IgnoreList = List(""," ","0","-","{}","()","[]","null","Null","NULL","false","False","FALSE","NA","na","Na","n/a","N/a","N/A","nil","Nil","NIL")
val df = sqlContext.sql(s"select userName from names where userName not in $IgnoreList")
```

But this won't work. I also tried:

```
val IgnoreList = List(""," ","0","-","{}","()","[]","null","Null","NULL","false","False","FALSE","NA","na","Na","n/a","N/a","N/A","nil","Nil","NIL")
sqlContext.udf.register("SqlList",(s: List[String]) => "('" + s.mkString("','") + "')")
val df = sqlContext.sql(s"select userName from names where userName not in SqlList($IgnoreList)")
```

But that won't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt fails because it calls List's default toString, which doesn't return the SQL-valid syntax that you need. Your second attempt fails because there's no sense in using a UDF to build the SQL string - UDFs are to be applied to *records* (or columns), not to create string queries.

You need the formatting done in the second, combined with the plain String interpolation done in the first:

```
val IgnoreList = List(""," ","0","-","{}","()","[]","null","Null","NULL","false","False","FALSE","NA","na","Na","n/a","N/a","N/A","nil","Nil","NIL")
val condition = "('" + IgnoreList.mkString("','") + "')"
val df = sqlContext.sql(s"select userName from names where userName not in $condition")
```

BTW, might be clearer to format the list this way:

```
IgnoreList.map(s => s"'$s'").mkString(",")
```